form not able to show invalid field when using a nested component
I have a form that looks like this:
form = formGroup({

  name:FormControl(''),
  adress:new FormGroup({
    city: new FOrmControl(''),
  })

})

and I use two components
parent:
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input matInput formControlName="name">
  <child-component [group]="form.controls.adress"><child-component/>
</form>

child:
<form [formGroup]="group">
  <input matInput formControlName="city">
</form>

Now my problem is that when I submit the form and city is invalid, the red underline doesn't show.
How can submit have an effect on both parent and child?

Please try the below code:
parent.component.html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.name.invalid && (form.controls.name.dirty || form.controls.name.touched)">
      Name is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <app-child [group]="addressGroup"></app-child>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

parent.component.ts
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiResponse } from '../models/apiResponse';
import { ChaptersViewModel } from '../models/chapters.model';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      address: new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }),
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.markAllAsTouched(this.form);
    if (this.form.valid) {
      // Handle valid form submission
    }
  }

  markAllAsTouched(group: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key) => {
      const control = group.get(key);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched();
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.markAllAsTouched(control);
      }
    });
  }

  get addressGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('address') as FormGroup;
  }
}

child.component.html
<form [formGroup]="group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="city" placeholder="City">
    <mat-error *ngIf="group.controls.city.invalid && (group.controls.city.dirty || group.controls.city.touched)">
      City is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

child.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() group!: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }  
}


A mat-error yet take account when touched an invalid. so you can remove the *ngIf. NOTE: From Angular 8 the formGroup have a method markAllAsTouched -you need't create it, directly: this.form.markAllAsTouched()
